# What slimes must I defeat for the Gelatin World Tour achievement?

Tags: terraria

The *Gelatin World Tour* achievement requires the user to *Defeat every type of slime there is!*

The [achievements page](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Achievements) at the official wiki indicates that there are 24 types of slimes, but the [list of slimes](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Slime) is much longer than that.

Which specific slimes are tracked for attaining this achievement?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [Chapter Cheats](http://www.chaptercheats.com/cheat/xbox360/111287/Terraria/hint/61743/):

> There are 29 different slimes in total, however only 24 of them need
> to be killed. The other five slimes are from Christmas and Halloween
> events. The slimes can be found as follows.
>
> Pre-Hardmode slimes
>
> - Green Slime: Found in the Forest during the day.
> - Blue Slime: Found in Forest and Underground, or summoned with a slime statue.
> - Red Slime: Found spawning in the Underground.
> - Purple Slime: Spawns on surface uncommonly in the outer thirds of the world.
> - Yellow Slime: Found in the Underground layer.
> - Black Slime: Spawn in the Cavern layer, and are hard to see.
> - Mother Slime: Second largest ordinary slimes. They spawn in Cavern layers.
> - Baby Slime: A few Baby Slimes will spawn after killing Mother Slime.
> - Pinky: Very rare slime that can appear in the Forest biome. It is the smallest of the slimes.
> - Jungle Slime: Common enemy in the Jungle biome.
> - Spiked Jungle Slime: Can be found in both Jungle and Underground Jungle Biomes.
> - Lava Slime: Spawn only in the Underworld. They have fiery glow and emit some light.
> - Dungeon Slime: Found in the Dungeon and have a Golden Key inside.
> - Ice Slime: Common enemy in a Snow Biome and also appear in the Underground Snow Biome.
> - Spiked Ice Slime: Commonly found in the Underground Snow Biome.
> - Umbrella Slime: Found during rain on the surface. They are larger than Blue and Green Slimes and hold an umbrella.
> - King Slime: Summoned with Slime Crown as well as by very rare random spawns when a player is in the two outer thirds of the map (far
>   left or far right), the depth is above zero, and there is standard,
>   green grass as a potential spawn point. Note: Goblin Scouts will spawn
>   in the same locations as King Slime, indicating the proper location
>   has been found.
>
> Hardmode slimes
>
> - Corrupt Slime: Can spawn in both The Corruption and Underground Corruption Biomes. Similar to Mother Slimes but stronger. It is a
>   Corruption counterpart to a Crimslime.
> - Slimeling: Three Slimelings will spawn after defeating a Corrupt Slime.
> - Crimslime: Found in the Crimson biome in different sizes. It is a Crimson counterpart to a Corrupt Slime.
> - Illuminant Slime: Spawn in the Underground Hallow Biome, replacing normal cave slimes. They emit a small amount of light.
> - Rainbow Slime: Rare spawn near The Hallow during rain or blizzard. They will spawn outside of The Hallow Biome while a player is
>   physically inside. It does not spawn directly on the hallowed blocks,
>   but on non-hallow blocks such as grass or snow.
> - Slimer: Spawn in The Corruption and Underground Corruption Biomes. It begins as a flying Slime with wings but will lose them and fight
>   you on ground.
> - Toxic Sludge: Spawns in the Underground in place of
>   ordinary slimes.
> - Queen Slime: Summoned by the gelatin crystal

Comment: I don't understand. My bestiary shows me as having killed all of those but I still have one missing in the achievement.